# Access - Workaround for EXCEPT operator

Tags: ms-access

I'm new to Access and am trying to develop a query that would usually  have an EXCEPT operator.  What I have found so far indicates that the EXCEPT operator does not exist in Access. I've tried some join and some AND and OR statements and have not had any luck,

What I'm trying to do is get all the school codes (0000-9999).  However, all the 0* level courses should be NOT be included except for course 0702.  So the results would look like:

0702, 1000's, 2000's, etc...

This is a text field due to the leading zeros.

Here is my last attempt at SQL to get the above results:

```
SELECT [1ImportItSchoolData].Course_Key
FROM 1ImportItSchoolData
WHERE ( ([1ImportItSchoolData].Course_Key) Not Like "0*" OR  ([1ImportItSchoolData].Course_Key)="0702" );
```

This results in records with a course keys 1000 - 9999, course_key 0702 is not part of the resultant record set.
How do I get all the courses including 0702 but none of the other 0 level courses?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```sql
SELECT 
    Course_Key
FROM 
    1ImportItSchoolData
WHERE 
    Course_Key = "0702" Or Course_Key >= "1000";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it didn't work earlier but this SQL statement works.

```
SELECT [1ImportItSchoolData].Course_Key
FROM 1ImportItSchoolData
WHERE ((([1ImportItSchoolData].Course_Key)="0702") OR ([1ImportItSchoolData].Course_Key) Not Like "0*");
```